# Como posso ver as versões dos pacotes atualizados via composer?

Tags: php, composer

É bom e lindo ver o `Composer` instalando as depdendências de acordo com a versão que determinamos no PHP.

Tenho muitas aplicações onde utilizo o `Composer` e, nesse momento, precisou fazer atualização das bibliotecas em todas elas, por causa de uma correção de `bug` que foi lançada.

Preciso instalar as versão `4.2.3` de uma biblioteca, que da última vez que utilizei estava na `4.2.2`. Porém, como são muitos sistemas, não sei quais deles já atualizei ou não.

Como posso fazer para  ver as versão de um ou mais aplicativos que estão atualmente instalado no `Composer`?

Se tiver como fazer isso, ficará mais fácil, e os sistemas que eu detectar que já está com a versão que eu quero instalada basta ignorar e ir para o próximo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta utilizar o comando `composer show`

veja a doc completa aqui: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#show

Comment: Tomou -1 por quê? A resposta está certa, é isso mesmo. O único problema é que poderia ter mais detalhes

Answer (score 1):

A resposta acima disse muito bem, basta usar o comando `composer show`, e uma lista de pacotes aparecerão.

Percebi que as vezes é  necessário filtrar para poder achar um pacote específico, para você não ter que olhar linha por linha da listagem desses pacotes.

Nesse caso eu sugiro que utilize o comando:

```
 composer show | grep 'nome_do_pacote'
```

Se nada tiver sido instalado, esse comando não retornará nada na tela.

Answer (score 0):

Outro detalhe do show com grep que citaram acima é que você pode filtrar por proprietário do pacote:

`composer show | grep 'proprietario/pacote'`

mas pode filtrar pelo proprietário ou somente nome do pacote utilizando um caractere coringa:

`composer show | grep 'proprietario/*'`